# Phalcon Query super slow inside large loop

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization, phalcon

I'm using Phalcon 3.0.4. I made a foreach on each file inside my folder. Currently I have just 4000 files. I did a findFirst to check if the filename already exist in MySQL (I have 100 000 rows in my table). But when I use findFirst, the response is super slow (I have to wait 20 minutes to get a response). Here is my code :

```
 $dir = new FilesystemIterator("files/path/to/my/files/");
 foreach ($dir as $file) {
     if ($file->getExtension() == 'json') {
         $filename = $file->getFilename();
         $explode_filename = explode("_", $filename);
         $date = $explode_filename[0];

         $unformatted_date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Ymd-His", $date);
         $date_server = $unformatted_date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

         $timestamp_app = $explode_filename[2];
         $date_app = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp_app/1000);
         echo $date_server;
         $json_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

         $scan = Scans::findFirst(array(
             "name = :name:",
             "bind" => array("name" => $filename)
         ));

         if  (!$scan) {
             ...
         }
     }
 }
```

I tried to make my query with the QueryBuilder PHQL but I have the same result:

```
$scan = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
                                ->from("Scans")
                                ->where("name = :name:", ["name" => $filename])
                                ->limit(1)
                                ->getQuery()
                                ->execute();
```

If I remove the findFirst or queryBuilder the response is ~30ms but with the findFirst it will takes ~20 minutes... How can I do to increase the performance of the search in my table ?

Comment: Maybe adding an index on "name" column will give you a performance boost https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

Comment: Oh yes you right, very nice suggestion !

Answer (score 0):

By changing your code to better performing one:

```
$dir = new FilesystemIterator("files/path/to/my/files/");
$fileNames = [];
foreach ($dir as $file) {
    if ($file->getExtension() == 'json') {
        $filename = $file->getFilename();
        $explode_filename = explode("_", $filename);
        $date = $explode_filename[0];

        $unformatted_date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Ymd-His", $date);
        $date_server = $unformatted_date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $timestamp_app = $explode_filename[2];
        $date_app = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp_app/1000);
        echo $date_server;
        $json_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
        // save the above data to some arrays

        $fileNames[] = $fileName;
    }
}

$scans = Scans::find([
    'columns' => 'check only columns you need, otherwise you will have full models with hydration',
    'conditions' => 'name IN ({fileNames:array})',
    'group' => 'name',
    'bind' => [
        'fileNames' => $fileNames
    ]
]);

foreach($fileNames as $fileName) {
    $filteredScans = $scans->filter(function($scan) use ($fileName) {
        return $scan->name == $fileName;
    }

    if(!$filteredScans) {
        // do here whatever
    }
}
```

This solution can be memory heavy though, then you could include here some paginations like do some limit like proper for and do 100-10000 rows at once depending how much RAM you have.

Comment: Set an index on my name field works fine and your solution too

Comment: Yea index of course is necessary :) Also if you use mysql then switch to mariadb 10.1

My solution will be more memory heavy - if you can spare additional memory it sure will be faster then selecting one row in loop.

Comment: But with your solution I can't make the condition, if !scan then I do something

Comment: But you don't need to do it here, you are finding scans WHERE name is one of file names, if there is no such row with such file name it won't be returned from database so this check is not needed. Oh wait you have there `!$scan`, then just change it to NOT IN.

Comment: I need to add the json file data if the filename doesn't exist in my table

Comment: Yea yea, updated answer, there should be NOT IN. But you surely need to add here some limit, and do select like 100-1000 rows at once, cuz finding 96000 rows will be memory heavy.

Comment: And I have to store in variable all json data foreach files ? xD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137676/discussion-between-juri-and-john).

Answer (score -2):

1. create index on Scans.name
2. use group by Scans.name (if not uniq)
3. set some columns then be use